# Get Filename from External Process File Handle for Win64bit - C#

Tags: c#, windows, process, systems-programming, windows64

can somebody please help me.

I want to get the filename that corresponds to a file handle of an external process.

Currently i managed to do that only on Win32bit and not Win64bit.

Is code signing required to do that in Windows 64bit ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you post the 32 bit code? Maybe someone can point out any error, or otherwise someone else might find it helpful as it is. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CreateFileMapping for Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531933/createfilemapping-for-directory)

Comment: What scenario could possibly require this sort of functionality? Don't mess with the handles of other processes.

Comment: @RaymondChen hopefully its for informational or diagnostic use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your application as AnyCPU (not x86), because on an x64 OS only x64 processes can access other x64 processes.